# not able to create const object of class derived from std::vector

Tags: c++, stl

I am deriving stl container class vector and trying to overload the [] operators to provide range checking on accessing element with subscript.
But I get compile errors when try to create const object of my derived class `Vec`.

For example below is the code:

```
template<class T>
class Vec : public vector<T>
{
    public:
    Vec(): vector<T>()
    {
    }
    Vec(int i):vector<T>(i)
    {
    }
    T& operator[](int i)
    {
        return at(i);
    }
    const T& operator[](int i) const
    {
       if(i>=size())
       cout<<"error"<<endl;
       return at(i);
    } 
};

void main()
{
    Vec<int> v1(10); //works fine
    const Vec<int> v(10); //error                                
}
```

Why the code 
    const vector v(10); works but
    const Vec v1(10); doesn't work.
    Is there something I am missing? Why am I not able to create const object?

Comment: Do us a favor and post your *real* code. The error your describing, if it is in this posting, is dwarfed by the numerous other errors.

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to reproduce your problem with g++ 4.5 (after fixing issues like `void main`, missing includes, and not qualifying non-dependent names with `this->`). Can you please offer any further clarification to help us?

Comment: @MarkB ditto that.

Comment: The code as posted compiles without errors for me in Visual Studio 2005.  What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STL classes like `std::vector` are generally not meant to be derived from.

But the code works correctly like this:

```
template<class T>
class Vec : public vector<T>
{
    public:
    Vec(): vector<T>()
    {
    }
    Vec(int i):vector<T>(i)
    {
    }
    T& operator[](int i)
    {
        return vector<T>::at(i);
    }
    const T& operator[](int i) const
    {
       if(i>=vector<T>::size())
       cout<<"error"<<endl;
       return vector<T>::at(i);
    } 
};

int main()
{
    Vec<int> v1(10); //works fine
    const Vec<int> v(10); //error                                
    v1.push_back(5);
    v1.push_back(6);
    int i = v1[3];
}
```

The functions `at` and `size` from the base `std::vector` need to be called with using either `vector<T>::at(i)` or `this->at(i)`.
This is always true when the base class is a template: Then "`vector<T>`" is a dependent name (its meaning depends on the template argument `T`), and in that case its members are not automatically exported to the scope of the `Vec` class definition.

Also `cout<"error"` must be `cout<<"error"`, and `main` must return an `int`.

`const` does not pose a problem in this case.

In general, `push_back` cannot be used on a `const std::vector`, because it modifies the vector. But copy initialization or list initialization can be used to create a non-empty `const std::vector`. For example

```
const std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3};
```

Answer (score 0):

Bjarne Stroustrup covers this issue in "A Tour of C++".

```
template<typename T>
class Vec : public std::vector<T> {
public:
    using vector<T>::vector;      // use the constructors from vector (under the name Vec)

    T& operator[](int i)
    { return vector<T>::at(i); }

    const T& operator[](int i) const
    { return vector<T>::at(i); }
}
```

"Vec inherits everything from vector except for the subscript operations that it redefines to do range checking."